# How best to display a grid of 4x4 images in an Android app/game?

Tags: java, android, xml, grid

I am currently creating a whack-a-mole type game for a university assignment and I need to know how best to display the holes on screen. I have had a look at GridView, GridLayout and TableLayout and am confused as to which one I should pick considering I later need to make various clickables pop up from each hole. The Overall screen should simply have a banner at the top that will display score, lives etc. and a pause button at the bottom with a 4x4 grid in the middle displaying the holes. I am relatively new to XML and Java so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use gridview it's rather easy to implement and as name describes, it shall give your a proper grid of your choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, easy enough with GridLayout, but then you have limitation of using SDK > 14.

Easy 4 lines of code to make 4 x 4 grid:

```
        gridContainer = new GridLayout(this);
        gridContainer.setColumnCount(4);
        YOUR_OWN_VIEW.addView(gridContainer);

        for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++) 
        {
            ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
            img.setImageDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));

            gridContainer.addView(img, Math.max(0, gridContainer.getChildCount()));
        }
```

code above is for reference. May you need to change the images, size per your need. "YOUR_OWN_VIEW" - change to your view name.

Comment: That seems pretty good, thanks. What do I need to import to get gridContainer to be recognised though?

Comment: You can add GridLayout in your activity either in XML, or in Java code. I'm not sure what do you mean by recognized. If you want all of those 16 images be user touchables (is that what you mean recognised? ), then instead of adding images, add Buttons, add image as background resource to each button, and set OnClickListener to each button. 
Would appreciate if you up-vote the answer that works for you. :)

Comment: Sorry it took so long to get back to you. Turns out I was just being an idiot. I got it fixed in the end. I would upvote but I do not have enough rep. Thanks a lot for your help.