# Random square in a grid

Tags: java, android, grid

I'm working on an Android app and I want to make a system with a 4x4 grid. When the user clicks on a button, I want a random square of the grid being colored in. Is this possible in any way? I hope you can help.

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21052224/how-best-to-display-a-grid-of-4x4-images-in-an-android-app-game) on grids

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the above scenario using the following approach.

Making an assumption here that 4X4 grid has rows numbered from `0 to 3` and columns numbered from `0 to 3` i.e

```
(0,0) | (0,1) | (0,2) | (0,3)
(1,0) | (1,1) | (1,2) | (1,3)
(2,0) | (2,1) | (2,2) | (2,3)
(3,0) | (3,1) | (3,2) | (3,3)
```

Now you use a random Int generator in Java. Something like this:-

```
Random generator = new Random(); 
int x = generator.nextInt(4);
int y = generator.nextInt(4);
```

Basically the above code generates x value in the range - `[0,3]` and same for y as well.

Now you have random x and y values within the range and now you can access the grid cell and color it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for this usefull comment. This was one of my ideas but i have no idea how i can make a grid in Android Studio.

Comment: I mean it's not about Android Studio, do you know Java, you can create ArrayList<ArrayList<Integers>> this will give you a 2D - grid.

Comment: Your question was about how to access grid cells randomly.